# Why do I get more results for querying all instances of a subclass than for a query on the "parent" class?

Tags: sparql, wikidata

According to wikidata, a battle is a subclass of a military operation. Yet, when I query for all instances of military operations I get 699 results, whereas for all battles I get 7399.

Query for Military Operations

```
SELECT ?label WHERE {
  ?subj wdt:P31* wd:Q645883.
  ?subj rdfs:label ?label.
  FILTER((LANG(?label)) = "en")
}
```

Query for Battles

```
SELECT ?label WHERE {
  ?subj wdt:P31* wd:Q178561.
  ?subj rdfs:label ?label.
  FILTER((LANG(?label)) = "en")
}
```

Military Operation: https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q645883

Battle: https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q178561

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your SPARQL query, in particular, the property path, is wrong.
Types are connected by subClassOf (`wdt:P279`), but you're asking for the closure of `instance-of` relations when using `wdt:P31*`

It has to be `wdt:P31/wdt:P279*`

See https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P279 and https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P31 for the difference.

Comment: thank you! So basically, my query for military operations returned only those military operations that were not also a subclass, so entries that were also of subclass battle were not returned. Is this correct?